# solve Equations with Modulus(%)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have been working on this for a while now and not seem to solve this equation. The part that tripping me off is the mod. How do I take it to the other side so I can solve for $x$.

Suppose: $X = 10, a=20, z=30$, how to solve for smaller $x$.
$X=a^x \bmod z$

I tried using logs but answer is wrong. Could someone please guide me on how to do this?

Comment: You want to solve $10=20^{x}\pmod{30}$. This means that $20^x-10=30k$ for some integer $k$. That's the meaning of the $\pmod{30}$ notation. But $20^{x}-10=(30-10)^x-10=(-10)^x-10+30K$ for some integer $K$. If you put $x=1$ you get $(-10)^x-10=-20$, which is not divisible by $30$. But if you put $x=2$, you get $(-10)^x-10=100-10=90=3\times 30$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:
 Calculating the first powers of $20$ mod.$30$, you can conjecture (and prove) that
$$20^n\equiv 20\quad\text{if $n$ is odd}, \qquad 20^n\equiv 10\quad\text{if $n$ is even.} $$

Answer (score 0):

$x$ is even is a solution.
 $10\equiv20^x(mod30)$

10,20,30 all are divisible by 10
 $10\equiv 1(mod3)$

$20^x\equiv2^x(mod 3)$

But 30 is a multiple of 3

Therefore $20^x\equiv1(mod 3)$
 This is possible for $x$ is even